# Remove or replace some text from XPath string

Tags: xpath

Is it possible to remove or replace text on XPath string?

Using XPath I get url with http://www and I want to remove http://www, so the same XPath query would return me only a link without http://www. I can't find anything about removing or replacing Xpath string.

Is it possible?
If so, how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried `substring-after`?

```
substring-after('http://www.stackoverflow.com', 'http://www.')
```

Example:

```
<demo>http://www.stackoverflow.com</demo>
```

XPath:

```
//demo/substring-after(., 'http://www.')
```

Yields:

```
stackoverflow.com
```

Check [online demo here](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cdemo%3Ehttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com%3C%2Fdemo%3E&=%3Cdemo%3Ehttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com%3C%2Fdemo%3E&extract=%2F%2Fdemo%2Fsubstring-after(.%2C%20%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.%27)%0A%0A&=%2F%2Fdemo%2Fsubstring-after(.%2C%20%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.%27)%0A&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2).

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work for me :( I need it for Data-Miner extension for chrome. Maybe there are some other ways to do this?

Comment: `substring-after(//demo/text(), 'http://www.')` should also work. But I downloaded (I think) the extension you mentioned and it didn't work also. What did work was to not use the `substring-after` in the **Identify a Container** XPath expression, but to use it in the **Xpath for Columns**: where you have `.`, you place something like `substring-after(., "//")` (try it in this page).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to remove or replace text on XPath string.

As per your query, you want to replace the "http://www" with blank so that you can compare remaining portion of the value.

You can achieve this by using translate function, as shown below

Suppose this is your html

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Then this will be your xpath

```
//a[translate(@href,'http://www.','')='google.com']"
```

To read more about how translate works visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/translate