# Xpath - how to get all regular text as well as from a few embedded under tags (span etc.)

Tags: xpath

### Sample text is like this:

```
<div class='xyz'>
This is a great opportunity <span class='abc'>Thanks to Steve for that</span>.
And, this can be <strong>marketed</strong> to a larger market. 
<ad>bla bla</ad>
So, eventually European sector is out goal.
</div>
```

---

I like to get the text inside div class='xyz', but exclude the content inside the "span" and "ad", and, include the text under "strong".

What could be a possible Xpath query to achieve this.

I haven't tried anything and wondering how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to search for the `div` with the class you want, and within that `div`, search for *text nodes* (i.e. nodes which match the [node test](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-tests) `text()`), and then use a [*predicate*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates) (a boolean expression in square brackers) to filter out the text nodes which are contained somewhere within `span` or `ad` elements:

```xpath
//div[@class='xyz']/descendant::text()[not(ancestor::span | ancestor::ad)]
```

The sub-expression `ancestor::span | ancestor::ad` will return a list of the `span` or `ad` elements which enclose the context node. So in the predicate above, the expression `not(ancestor::span | ancestor::ad)` will return `true` if the current text node has no such ancestor elements, and `false` if the context node is inside a `span` or an `ad`. When the predicate is `true`, the text node is retained in the list to be returned, and if the predicate is `false`, the text node is excluded from the result.

The various [*axes*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#axes) used here (`ancestor`, `descendant`, etc) specify the *directions* which the steps in the XPath expression take inside the XML document, i.e. from an element to the things inside it, or to the elements that enclose it, or to the nodes that follow or precede it, etc.

**alternative**

The approach I describe above is to find all the text nodes which are descendants of the `div` and then exclude the ones which are also descendants of a `span` or an `ad`, but there's another possible approach, which is to find all the text nodes which are direct children of the `div`, and also add the text nodes which are children of a `strong` child of the `div`

```xpath
//div[@class='xyz']/text() | //div[@class='xyz']/strong/text()
```

This produces the same result as the XPath above, when applied to your sample XML, but it may differ if you have other child elements such as e.g. an `em` element. Do you want to have to list all the child elements whose text you *do* want to capture, or is it simpler to list the elements whose text you want to *ignore* (as my first XPath does). I suspect the first XPath probably more reliably reflects your needs, but I might be wrong, there.

Comment: Thanks Conal. This worked. Also appreciate the explanation of how it works.

Comment: Just updated my answer to point out another approach which may or may not be preferable (probably not, but I thought it worth including for completeness)

Answer (score 0):

Using XMLStarlet, and this question/answer:[Remove or replace some text from XPath string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258486/remove-or-replace-some-text-from-xpath-string)

you can do:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m //div -v substring-before(.,span) -o " " -v substring-after(.,span)   input.xml
```

this  will get the results without the `span` tag:

```
This is a great opportunity  .
And, this can be marketed to a larger market.
bla bla
So, eventually European sector is out goal.
```

Extending this also exclude the `ad` tag should be possible, but I would like to leave that work to you, because that would start to become to complex for my Sunday-morning....

P.S.: [xmlstarlet](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is:

> XMLStarlet is a set of command line utilities (tools) which can be
> used to transform, query, validate, and edit XML documents and files
> using simple set of shell commands in similar way it is done for plain
> text files using UNIX grep, sed, awk, diff, patch, join, etc commands.

Comment: Thanks Luuk for your response. I already got the answer from another post.